# NoMethodError: undefined method 'move_to'

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to work with the action builder in Ruby WebDriver and I am receiving this undefined method error when I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
driver.move_to(LOCATOR_FOO_CONSTANT).perform
```

I'm hoping I'm just tired, but I've been at this for hours and have looked everywhere I can think of.  The class doesn't have an initialize method like `Wait` or `Support::Select`.  I can not figure out how to use these methods.

If I type the following in RubyMine, I get access to the methods like `move_to` and `perform`, but receive an error for the wrong number of parameters for the initialize method.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::ActionBuilder.new.
```

Thank you.  I'm completely stuck and burned out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax and use is as follows:

```
el = driver.find_element(:id, "some_id")
driver.action.move_to(el).perform
```

Comment: Thank you Richard.  My issue was complicated by native events issues in Firefox.  Can't thank you enough for the correct syntax that allowed me to isolate the other issues I was causing myself.